# How can I pass model to action method from popup dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog, popup

I want to pass model to action method in my controller to edit that model with popup dialog. But input parameter that sanded to action method is not filled with data.

Here is HTML code from my View that calls popup dialog:

```
<span class="label label-border">
      <input class="edit_company" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="getForm()" />
</span>

<div id="dialog"></div>
```

JavaScript to call popup dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getForm() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'My Table',
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {

                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Edit", "Company", Model)');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

... and here is my action method that calls from JavaScript but data in it is not filled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check what is the URL in your `load` command. Just check the script code generated.
You'd better to use company ID in the URL:

```
 $(this).load('@Url.Action("Edit", "Company", new {id=Model.id})');
```

and in the controller load company data by id

```
public PartialViewResult Edit(int id)
{
    //code to retrive your company from the database by id
    return PartialView();
}
```